# Open gridview on click of another grid view in xamarin android

Tags: c#, gridview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new in Android as well Xamarin [image: grid view with image and text]

on click of grid view wont to open new activity with another grid view
[image: grid view with image and text]

**ImageAdadapter.cs**

```
 public class ImageAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
     public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view;

            if (convertView == null)
            {  
                view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.My_Grid_row, parent, false);

            }
            else
            {
                view = convertView;
            }


            var imageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.my_image_view);
            imageView.SetImageResource(thumbIds[position]);

            var Hastagtext = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.my_text_view);
            Hastagtext.SetText(MainTagsName[position]);

            //imageView.SetImageResource(thumbIds[position]);
            return view;
        }

        // references to our images
        int[] thumbIds = {
        Resource.Drawable.Icon, Resource.Drawable.Icon,
    };
        int[] MainTagsName = {
    Resource.String.Custom_tab_label,
            Resource.String.Custom_tab_label, Resource.String.All_tab_label

        };
    }
```

But i don't know how to do that.plese help me.